# ffmpeg FLAC 24 bit 96khz to 16 bit 48khz

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, bitrate, flac

Trying to figure out ffmpeg, currently working on getting 24bit/96khz FLAC files into 16bit/48khz.

Comment: 11 upvotes for the answer and 0 for the question?!

Answer (score 36):

## Basic example

```
ffmpeg -i input.flac -sample_fmt s16 -ar 48000 output.flac
```

- List sample formats: `ffmpeg -sample_fmts`
- List additional flac encoding options: `ffmpeg -h encoder=flac`

## [aresample](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#aresample) filter example

```
ffmpeg -i input.flac -af aresample=out_sample_fmt=s16:out_sample_rate=48000 output.flac
```

Either example will result in the same output: you can verify with the [hash muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#hash).

---

#### Changing the dithering method

See the [`-dither_method` option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-resampler.html) for a list of available dithering methods and additional resampling options. Example:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flac -dither_method triangular_hp -sample_fmt s16 -ar 48000 output.flac
```

---

#### SoX resampler

FFmpeg supports two resamplers: the default swresample library, and the external [SoX resampler](https://sourceforge.net/p/soxr/) (soxr).

To use soxr your `ffmpeg` must be compiled with `--enable-libsoxr`. Then choose it with the `-resampler` option:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flac -resampler soxr -sample_fmt s16 -ar 48000 output.flac
```

Or use the [aresample](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#aresample) filter to do it all:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flac -af aresample=resampler=soxr:out_sample_fmt=s16:out_sample_rate=48000 output.flac
```

---

#### More info

- [FFmpeg Resampler Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-resampler.html)

Answer (score 6):

As a bash script, that produces new files with -16 appended to their names; one could rename then delete the original files easily in the script but I'm a little too paranoid for that.

```
#!/bin/sh
# requires: ffmpeg
for f in *.flac;
do
echo "Processing $f"
ffmpeg -i "$f" -sample_fmt s16 -ar 48000 "${f%.flac}-16.flac"
done
```